# jwplayer 'share' image won't go away

Tags: jwplayer

At the end of playing a video, the jwplayer displays a "share" 
UI that covers the entire jwplayer rectangle -- this is a tabbed window with 3 tabs, 'share', 'embed', 'info.'
I need to make this 'Share' UI go away.

To replace this 'share' UI, which I assume the Jwplayer is putting up after completing 
playback of a video as standard behavior -- I added event handlers for the onIdle, onComplete and onReady
events.

In the event handlers I do exactly what the code does when the 
player is created:  I load a playlist with a default video and default image:

```
// this is called immediately after jwplayer.setup()
jwplayer().onComplete(function playerOnCompleteEvent(){handlePlayerComplete(jwplayer);});

// this gets called for the onComplete event
function handlePlayerComplete(theJwPlayer)
{
   playlist = { file: 'http://localhost/theWebsite/videos/moto_sounds.flv',
             image: 'http://localhost/theWebsite/images/mybanner2.jpg' };

   alert("in handlePlayerIdle:  the playlist file is "
                      + playlist.file + " and image is " + playlist.image);                 

   theJwPlayer().load(playlist);
}
```

The 'alert' box has told me that the playlist file and image are correct. 
And I know my event handlers are being called -- I use an alert box inside the handler to prove that to myself.

But the 'share' 3-tabbed window won't go away.  It is still there after playback -- 
the onIdle and onReady both use the same code above -- no help.

The 'share' UI -- how can I replace it with 'mybanner2.jpg' after a video playback
completes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you download jwplayer, make sure you choose the version that does not include the "viral" plugin, which is what you are seeing.  If you want to keep it in the menu of the video, then you can set a parameter to not allow it to run when a video completes.  I use the jwplayer.js file to put the player on my page, so my setup looks like this (it turns off the viral plugin screen on the completion of the video, and on pause):

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
  'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
  'file': 'http://www.linktovideo.com/video.mp4', 
  'image': 'video-screen-ss.jpg',
  'height': '380',
  'width': '512',
  'dock': 'true', 
  'stretching': 'uniform',
  'plugins': {
      'viral-2': {'oncomplete':'False','onpause':'False','functions':'All'}
    },
  'events': {
        onReady: function(event){ alert("player is ready"); }
   }
  });
```