# Removing "share - embed - info" tab boxes from jwplayer 6

Tags: jquery, jwplayer

Can you please let me know how I can remove the" share - embed- info" tab boxes from jwplayer?
this is too annoying in case of pause state or at the end of video.

[image]

I have seen some hints on the web to download the player unchecking the "viral" box, however such an option doesn't exist on JW Player 6 download page.

now can you please let me know how to get rid of this box?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Reference From: 
[jwplayer 'share' image won't go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485739/jwplayer-share-image-wont-go-away)

Use below attribute in your code.

1. 'plugins': {
         'viral-2': {'oncomplete':'False','onpause':'False','functions':'All'}
       }

Answer (score 0):

It's working absolutely fine for me.

I have used 'plugins':

```
{ 
    'viral-2': 
    {'
        oncomplete':'False','onpause':'False','functions':'All'
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.